# Is there an available network analysis of all academic papers and/or a 3D representation?

Tags: reference-request, bibliometrics

I know multiple paid or open databases are available online for a meta-analysis of academic articles, but I was wondering if there are any published papers or graphics on a network analysis of the available data, particularly in reference to time.

Ideally, what I’m looking for is a three-dimensional representation of correlation of all available research papers by word similarity, keyword, title similarity, etc. and with vertical axis as time of publication and which allowed relatively assessable identification of nodes, density, cluster, and relationship patterns.

If something like this exists, a link would be greatly appreciated. If not, any nudge in the right direction of meta-research on academia would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I seem to remember someone talking about this. That being said, I don't remember how to search for the thing.

Comment: Thanks; if you remember or find out, please let me know!

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14258/visualization-tool-for-paper-citations

Comment: Also related: [Can you get statistical data on research paper submissions and publications?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30898/can-you-get-statistical-data-on-research-paper-submissions-and-publications/44929#44929)

Comment: If you want to read a paper like that, write it yourself.

Comment: What do you intend to do with this information? It is somewhat a specific question, but I wonder if there are other solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would google something like "PageRank for Research Papers", since PageRank is Google's algorithm for ranking webpages based on network analysis. Google scholar is handy for finding how many citations a paper has and which papers it has been cited by.