# It is possible to get Arxiv article metadata from its article ID?

Tags: arxiv

Is there a file that gives an article's title, author, etc by article id? For instance, given archive id 1411.7990 I would like to be able to find the title "Irreducible Representations..." via a search through a document. In other words, can one search the arxiv remotely?

Comment: I don't understand this question - can't you just retrieve `http://arxiv.org/abs/ID` and parse the HTML?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have a large set of id's I would like to match with title's.

Comment: For a large set, use one of their [bulk data access](http://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data) options

Comment: @ff524 Already did. The thing is the files are all identified by article id without titles.

Comment: So.. what's the question? I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking about. Where, exactly, are you stuck?

Comment: There is some free software online, Mendelay Desktop which provides title's for papers after archiving them. This solved my problem although the question still remains if there is a readily available list of all arxiv papers published online.

Comment: Have you seen http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38969/getting-a-dump-of-arxiv-metadata ? It might answer your question or at least help.

Answer (score 3):

The python script on [this page](http://www.thamnos.de/misc/look-up-bibliographical-information-from-an-arxiv-id/) seems to work. You can modify it easily to output the information you need instead of a bibtex entry.